# Find substring from a complex string using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a String containing huge script code as follows :

```
String script = "node {
    stage(someString) {
        try {
            **parameters= [
                [someString],
        [someString],
        [someString],
        [someString],
        [someString],
        [someString],
            [someString],
            ]**
            //some more script
    }
}";
```

I want to extract the parameters variable containing array of array values

I tried the following pattern but didnt work

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("parameters= [(.*?)]");
```

How do I extract the parameters variable from script String variable using Regex?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Mandy8055 And use the `(?s)` dot all flag in the regex pattern.

Comment: `.*?parameters=\s\[((?s).*)?(\]\*\*)` - first group should contain everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using:

```
parameters=\s*\[(.*)]
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`parameters=`** - Matches `parameters=` literally.
- **`\s*`** - Matches a white-space character zero or more times.
- **`\[`** - Matches `[` literally.
- **`(.*)]`** - represents a capturing group capturing everything before a `]`.

---

[image: Pictorial Representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/BEtTtt/3/)

**Sample Implementation in java:**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Main
{
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("parameters=\\s*\\[(.*)]", Pattern.DOTALL);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "node {\n"
     + "    stage(someString) {\n"
     + "        try {\n"
     + "            **parameters= [\n"
     + "                [someString],\n"
     + "        [someString],\n"
     + "        [someString],\n"
     + "        [someString],\n"
     + "        [someString],\n"
     + "        [someString],\n"
     + "            [someString],\n"
     + "            ]**\n"
     + "            //some more script";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    while(matcher.find()){
        // Replaced all the unwanted spaces and commas. You can address that accordingly.
        sb.append(matcher.group(1).replaceAll("[\\s,]+", " "));
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
}
```

Please find the sample run of the above implementation in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/SkoQSLEJw)

Comment: @Maha I'm glad I could help=) Cheers